# moment js muestra ayer en vez de hoy

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic

Tengo un problema, cuando intento mostrar una fecha en términos de hoy, ayer o mañana se visualiza ayer en vez de hoy.

Adjunto el código que utilizo

```
  let item = moment.utc(this.date);
  this.month = item.format(ENV.date.month).toLowerCase();
  console.log('Moment', moment.utc())
  console.log('Item date', item)
  this.formatDate = (moment.utc().diff(item, 'days') >= ENV.date.maxShow
    ? item.format(ENV.date.last) : item.calendar(moment.utc()));
```

Ejemplo:

> **Moment** Fri Aug 30 2019 01:14:49 GMT+0000 // La fecha del celular en el 29 de agosto no del 30 de agosto
>
> **Item** date Thu Aug 29 2019 18:09:31 GMT+0000 // Muestra ayer en vez de hoy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando la hora global, por eso tienes la diferencia horaria. Para solucionarlo debes declarar la función en hora local de la siguiente manera:

```js
var date = moment.utc().format();
console.log(date, "- Hora global UTC"); 

var local = moment.utc(date).local().format();
console.log(local, "- Hora local UTC");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```